# Remove outliers from a point cloud

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy, vectorization

This function accepts a cloud of points, and returns those points that are within `delta` distance of the average (mean) position.

```
def points_average(points,delta):
    """ this function will check, for every point in points 
    what are the points that are near the point (below a distance delta) 
    it will then average every such points, creating a new list of points. 
    This will continue until we arrive at a fixed amount of points """


    L = math.inf
    n = 0

    while L > len(points):

        L = len(points)

        points2 = []

        for i in xrange(len(points)):

            pt = points[i]
            d = (pt[0]-points[:,0])**2.+(pt[1]-points[:,1])**2.
            pts = points[d<delta**2.]

            x = np.average(pts[:,0])
            y = np.average(pts[:,1])

            points2 += [[x,y]]

        points2 = np.array(points2)
        points = np.unique(points2,axis=0)
        print len(points)

    return points
```

The function can be tested with:

```
import numpy as np

delta = 1
points = np.random.uniform(0,100,(500,2))
new_pts = simplify_by_avg_weighted(points,delta)
```

Please review the code for any improvements.  In particular, I would like to replace the `for` loop with a numpy vectorized version - any advice towards that would be welcome.

Comment: I've made a substantial edit to your description of the problem solved by this program, to bring it into line with site standards - please check whether I've misunderstood anything, and if necessary [edit] to correct it.

Comment: Take a look on an KDTree approach. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459306/find-points-within-cutoff-distance-of-other-points-with-scipy

Comment: I guess that is the function you are searching for scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_tree  
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_tree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_tree

Comment: @max9111 thank you for the suggestion, I made it work

Answer (score 3):

Please add a docstring.

`Simplify_by_avg_weighted` might be named `points_near_centroid` (or `_center` if you prefer).

Please initialize with `L = math.inf`, to clarify your intent.

Rather than a variable length list for `[x,y,1]`, please store it as a 3-tuple `(x, y, 1)`, or more naturally as a pair `((x, y), 1)`, where 1 is a count rather than a spatial coordinate.

```
    for i in xrange(len(points)):
```

This would more naturally be expressed as `for pt in points:`.

Now we come to the heart of the matter. It's a little hard to evaluate the code in the loop, as it seems to differ from your English language description, and it's hard to declare a "violates spec" bug when there's no docstring offering a spec.

When you assign x, y, they might better have names like `x_centroid`. And since z is not a spatial coordinate, it would more appropriately be named `count`. It's fine that you don't take square root, but d should have a name like `dsq` for distance squared.

To "return those points that are within delta of the mean position", does the interpreter even need to loop? It should suffice to compute centroid of the whole cloud (numpy does the looping), then select on distance (more numpy looping).

Answer (score 2):

This is the result I got thanks to the KDTree approch suggested by max9111. It is indeed much faster as I do not compute the distances but only specify a cutoff distance:

```
def simplify_by_avg(points, cutoff):

    points = np.unique(points, axis = 0)
    points = np.hstack((points, np.ones((points.shape[0], 1), dtype=points.dtype)))

    L = np.inf
    n = 0
    print len(points),"points, n=",n

    while L > len(points):
        n += 1
        L = len(points)

        tree = spatial.cKDTree(points[:,0:2])
        groups = tree.query_ball_point(points[:,0:2], delta)

        new_pts = []

        for i in xrange(len(groups)):

            ind = groups[i]
            pts = points[ind]
            x = np.average(pts[:,0])
            y = np.average(pts[:,1])
            z = np.sum(pts[:,2])

            new_pts += [[x,y,z]]

        points = np.unique(new_pts,axis=0)

        print len(points),"points, n=",n

    return points
```